# Finding files in list using bash array loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that reads a file with filenames, and outputs whether or not those files were found in a directory.

Logically I'm thinking it goes like this:

```
$filelist = prompt for file with filenames
$directory = prompt for directory path where find command is performed

new Array[] = read $filelist line by line

for i, i > numberoflines, i++
     if find Array[i] in $directory is false 
        echo "$i not found"
export to result.txt
```

I've been having a hard time getting Bash to do this, any ideas?

Comment: You can use `if [ -f "$dir/$file" ]` to see if a `file` is inside a `dir`.

Comment: search here for `[bash] find xargs` and you should find many articles to give you ideas. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would just assume that all the file-names are supplied on standard input. E.g., if the file `names.txt` contains the file-names and `check.sh` is the script, you can invoke it like

```
cat names.txt | ./script.sh
```

to obtain the desired behaviour (i.e., using the file-names from `names.txt`).

Second, inside `script.sh` you can loop as follows over all lines of the standard input

```
while read line
do
  ... # do your checks on $line here
done
```

**Edit:** I adapted my answer to use standard input instead of command line arguments, due to the problem indicated by @rici.

Comment: If there are spaces in any filename, then that will break. The `"$@"` doesn't save it, because the words were already split by `$(cat filenames.txt)` (Ok, you didn't use `$()`, but it doesn't make any difference, and backticks are deprecated.)

Comment: @rici You are right. It would probably be better to read the input line-by-line instead of via arguments.

Comment: How would I use the vertical pipe inside of a script? I'm hoping to make this something that a person could just double click in Finder.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read dirname
do
  echo $dirname >> result.txt
  while read filename
  do
    find $dirname -type f -name $filename >> result.txt
  done <filenames.txt
done <dirnames.txt
```

Comment: How would I make `dirname` dynamic based on the location of the script, ie. script is located in `~/project/script.sh` so I want `dirname` to automatically be `~/project/`? Same with `filenames.txt`   **edit:** Sorry nvm, I searched stackexchange and found the answer at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in`

Comment: I [found the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in) to my comment question about dynamic directories.